# Is this diffusion equation with particular Neumann b.c. is solvable at all?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the followin equation by separation of variables
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx} = 0          & 0 < x < L, t > 0\\
u(x,0) = x              & 0 < x < L\\
u_x(0,t) = u_x(L,t) = 0 & t > 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
I found this solution:
$$\boxed{u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(A_n\cos{\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)}e^{-\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}t}\right)}.$$
But i can't fit initial value conditions at $x = 0.$
My calculations are like this:
$$
\begin{align*}
A_n &= \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L x\cos{\frac{\pi n x}{L}} dx\\
&= \frac{2}{L}\frac{L}{\pi n}\left(x\sin{\frac{\pi n x}{L}}|_0^L-\int_0^L\sin\frac{\pi nx}{L}dx\right)\\
&= \frac{2L}{\pi^2 n^2}\cos\frac{\pi nx}{L}|_0^L\\
&= \begin{cases}
-\frac{4L}{\pi^2 n^2}&n\ \mbox{is odd}\\
0 &\mbox{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
EDIT: Hmm.. looks like initial conditions don't include $0.$

Comment: Your calculation looks good, you are just missing the value of $A_{0}$. You should find $A_{0} = 1$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your edit.

Comment: @Mattos i mean that i.c. are $0 < x < L$, so $0$ is not included. Now i'm thinking about why $A_0$ is $1.$

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean, your comment doesn't make sense. Do you mean the $0$ that is attributed to the bounds of the integral for the domain of $x$? Or the $t = 0$ for the initial condition?

Comment: The initial conditions and boundary conditions do not agree. In such cases you must be quite cautious about how you set the problem up.

Comment: @Mattos, i mean initial conditions not b.c. There is no condition that $u(0,0) = 0$

Comment: @Ian, the problem is from Sandra Salsa book on PDE

Comment: @Mattos why $A_0 = 1?$

Comment: @Yola Sorry, calculation error on my part. It should be $A_{0} = L/2$.

Comment: I'm not saying the problem can't be solved, but you have to be careful to set it up properly. Just blindly doing separation of variables will usually not work.

Comment: @Mattos could you publish your calculations, maybe as an answer

Comment: You have \begin{align}
u(x, 0) &= \sum_{k \ge 0} A_{k} \cos \left( \frac{k \pi x}{L} \right) \\
&= x
\end{align}

Multiplying both sides by $\cos \left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right)$ and integrating from $0 \to L$, we find

$$\int_{0}^{L} x \cos \left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) dx = \sum_{k \ge 0} A_{k} \int_{0}^{L} \cos \left( \frac{k \pi x}{L} \right) \cos \left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) dx$$

If $k = m = 0$

$$\int_{0}^{L} x dx = A_{0} \int_{0}^{L} dx$$

Integrating gives the result. Try yourself for $k = m \ne 0$, you should get the result you already gave above.